# How to fix 'Module com.google.common not found' error when creating a Selenium WebDriver class with ChromeDriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, functional-testing

While creating a simple Selenium webdriver class I'm getting the below error.

> **Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
> java.lang.module.FindException: Module com.google.common not found, required by org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver
> **

How will I get the module?